Doubt in the Proof of the Dehn-Nielsen-Baer Theorem
I am reading the book of Farb-Margalit "A primer on mapping class groups" and I can't understand one of the result in chapter 8 (i.e. "The Dehn-Nielsen-Baer Theorem"). Lemma 8.5 states that two hyperbolic elements $\gamma, \delta \in \pi_{1}(S_{g})$ are linked at infinity if and only if $\Phi(\gamma)$ and $\Phi ( \delta)$ are linked at infinity (where $\Phi$ is an automorphism of $\pi_{1}(S_{g})$).
We suppose that $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are not linked at infinity, and we choose a base point $x_{0} \in \mathbb{H}^{2}$. We then consider the orbit of $x_{0}$ under the action of $\gamma$ and we call that set $ \mathcal{O}_{\gamma}$.
We connect the points of $\mathcal{O}_{\gamma}$ by an infinite piecewise-geodesic path, where every segment connects two points in the orbit of $x_{0}$ under the action of $\pi_{1}(S_{g})$ (and not only $\gamma$) that lie in adjacent domains. We can choose this path to lie in some metric neighboorhood of the axes of $\gamma$.
What I don'tt understand is the last sentence: why can we choose this path to be in a metric neighboorhood of the axes of $\gamma$? Since $\gamma$ is an hyperbolic isometry of $\mathbb{H}^{2}$, we know that tere exist two points on $\partial \mathbb{H}^{2}$ (let's call them $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$) such that $\gamma^{k}$ tends to these points ad $k$ tends to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Therefore, I know that $\gamma^{k}(x_{0})$ tends to $y_{1}$ or $y_{2}$. I don't understand if these considerations are enough to say that the piecewise-geodesic path (that I've built before) lie in some metric neighboorhod of the axes of $\gamma$.
In any case, I am not sure if the convergence of two paths (one geodesic and the other one piecewise-geodesic) to same points on $\partial \mathbb{H}^{2}$ is sufficient to say that they lie in a metric neighboorhood of each other (because the distance is not defined on the boundary of $\mathbb{H}^{2}$).

Here's a precise description of the infinite piecegeodesic path, and a proof that it is contained in some metric neighborhood of the axis of $\gamma$. As you'll see, this doesn't have very much to do with convergence of two paths to the same points in $\partial\mathbb H^2$, it's really just a simple fact about groups acting by isometres on metric spaces. (On the other hand it can be applied to proofs of uniqueness of limit points on $\partial\mathbb H^2$, but that's not what you asked about.)
Let's start with the orbit of $x_0$ under the action of $\gamma$: denoting $x_k = \gamma^k(x_0)$ we have $\mathcal O_\gamma = \{x_k \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$.
Let's next construct the infinite piecewise geodesic path. Start with the unique geodesic $g_0$ that connects $x_0$ to $x_1$, denoted $g_0$. It follows for each $k \in \mathbb Z$ that $g_k = \gamma^k(g_0)$ is the unique geodesic that connects $x_k = \gamma^k(x_0)$ to $x_{k+1}=\gamma^{k+1}(x_0)=\gamma^k(\gamma(x_0))=\gamma^k(x_1)$. It also follows that $g_{k-1}$ and $g_k$ have a common endpoint $x_k$. So we can therefore form the bi-infinite concatenation
$$L = \cdots * g_{-2} * g_{-1} * g_0 * g_1 * g_2 * \cdots
$$
Also, let's use $\ell$ to denote the axis of $\gamma$.
Since $g_0$ is a compact segment, the exists $R \ge 0$ such that $g_0$ is contained in the $R$ neighborhood of $\ell$. And since $\gamma^k(g_0)=g_k$, and $\gamma^k(\ell)=\ell$, and $\gamma^k$ is an isometry, if follows that $g_k$ is also contained in the $R$ neighborhood of $\ell$. Finally, since $L$ is the union of all of the $g_k$, it follows that $L$ is contained in the $R$ neighborhood of $\ell$.

This, by the way, is an example of a very general fact about a group $G$ acting by isometries on a metric space $X$: given any compact sets $A,B \subset X$ there exists $R>0$ such that each point in the $G$-orbit of $A$ has distance $\le R$ from each point in the $G$-orbit of $B$; one just takes $R$ to be an upper bound for the distance between each point of $A$ and each point of $B$, and applies the same argument as above.
